# PHP: proper writing for code snippet (switch cases)

Tags: php, switch-statement

I am still pretty new to PHP and wrote the following code snippet as part of a longer code to create an email.

This is working fine but I was wondering if there is a way to get this more "automised" so that I dont have to write it manually for each file. 
As $varCount shows the number of files uploaded and I only want them added as a link ($varLink) and separated with a comma like below I thought maybe there is a way I can avoid writing all these cases.

**My code (working):**

```
switch($varCount)
{
    case '1':
        $message.="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $varLink1 . "<br /><br />";
        break;
    case '2':
        $message.="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $varLink1 . " , " . $varLink2 . "<br /><br />";
        break;
    case '3':
        $message.="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $varLink1 . " , " . $varLink2 . " , " . $varLink3 . "<br /><br />";
        break;
    default:
        $message.="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;No files uploaded<br /><br />";
        break;
}
```

Thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Put `varLinks` in array and use `implode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$varLink can be an array of all the links, Ex: `$varLinkArray`

```
if (!empty($varLinkArray)){
    $message.="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;" . implode(", ",$varLinkArray) . "<br /><br />";
}else {
    $message .= "<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;No files uploaded<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: Of course, in your solution as in the original question, `$message .= "<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;` should also be moved out of the body of *every* branch.

Comment: $message = '<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;' . (empty($varLinkArray) ? 'No files uploaded' : implode(', ', $varLinkArray)) . '<br /><br />';

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply - I'll try it this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have the $varLink1 variables in an array, you can reference them by their name with dynamic variable names:

```
    $message .= "<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
    $links = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $varCount; $i++) {
        $links[] = ${"varLink" . $i};
    }
    $message .= (count($links) == 0) ? "No files uploaded" : implode(" , ", $links);
    $message .= "<br /><br />";
```

Comment: Please, do not use `eval`. At least, use *dynamic variable names*, with `${"varLink" . $i}`

Comment: This looks great too - I'll try it as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to improve your code.

The first one would be to drop your *switch* statement, and use if blocks instead. Like this:

```
$message .= "<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
if ($varCount == 0) {
    $message .= "No files uploaded";
} else {
    $message .= $varLink1;
    if ($varCount >= 2) {
         $message .= ", " . $varLink2;
         if ($varCount >= 3) {
             $message .= ", " . $varLink3;
         }
    }
}
$message .= "<br /><br />";
```

As you can see, there is still a bit of redundancy, which could easily be removed by using [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.array.php) instead. Just iterate through the array, you do not even need `$varCount` anymore:

```
// $varLinks is your array
$message .= "<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";
if (empty($varLinks)) {
    $message .= "No files uploaded";
} else {
    $message .= join(", ", $varLinks);
}
$message .= "<br /><br />";
```

[`join()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) will convert your array by adding a glue (here, `", "`) in between each elements.

Answer (score 0):

If the links are not some pre-built static list, then this sort of functionality is best handled with loops. You'll want to do something like:

```
$message = "start of the string";
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $message .= "link for this particular $var";
}
$message .= "end of the string";
```

Answer (score 0):

This will produce the result of your question's code, except the default case.

```
$aVlinks = array($varLink1,$varLink2,$varLink3);

$message .="<strong>Attachments:</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;";

$message .= implode(",",array_slice($aVlinks,0,$varCount));

$message .= "<br><br>";
```